# Error while Uploading file to Google Cloud using Spring MVC and jQuery(Ajax)

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, google-cloud-storage

I am using Spring MVC and Ajax to Upload a file to server from webpage. Its working for normal client server model but when i'm hosting the war in google cloud, the file is not getting uploaded it throws error. Below is the code i have tried.

Jquery:

```
var jForm = new FormData();
jForm.append("selectSourceFile", $('#selectSourceFile').get(0).files[0]);

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: jForm,
    contentType: false,
    enctype:"multipart/form-data",  
    processData: false,
    async : false,
    url: "uploadInputFile",
    success: function(response) {
        moveNext();             
    },
    error : function(msg) {
    }
});
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadInputFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void uploadInputFile(HttpSession session, @RequestParam("selectSourceFile") MultipartFile file)
{
    if(file.getSize() != 0)
    {
        byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
        BufferedOutputStream outStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(session.getAttribute("appFolderPath") + file.getOriginalFilename())));
        outStream.write(bytes);

        if(outStream != null)
        {
            outStream.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Servlet xml:

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"> 
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="1000000" />
</bean>
```

Error in browser : **POST** *URL/uploadInputFile* **500 (INKApi Error)**

have tried using GMulitpart instead of Multipart too !

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.gmr.web.multipart.GMultipartResolver"> 
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="1000000" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) constructor takes a form in its constructor not a file. Use [FormData.append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) to add a file.

```
var jForm = new FormData();
jForm.append('selectSourceFile', $('#selectSourceFile').get(0).files[0]);
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: jForm,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    ...
});
```